# C# winforms: A problem with sending an email cointaining the image background

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve the problem:

I create the MailMessage object like that and send it:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
        mail.To.Add("login@gmail.com");

        mail.Subject = "This is an email";
        AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);


  (1)   AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");

        LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource("c:\\cop1.jpg");
        logo.ContentId = "companylogo";

        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

        mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Everything is OK, the mail has the image in the background.
But the problem is, when I change in the paragraph (1) from [(click)](http://pastebin.com/LNn6F8TN) to [(click)](http://pastebin.com/nAPgKkg0) everything fails, the image is not recognized and is threated as a attachment !

I think that is caused by the first colon here **background-image:cid:companylogo**

Is it possible to resolve that ?

Comment: I send it via

SmtpClient mailSender = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            mailSender.EnableSsl = true;
            mailSender.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass");
            mailSender.Send(mail);

Comment: What program are you viewing the email in?

Comment: in the FF, I just log into my @ inbox

Comment: OK, I tried in that way: <img src="C:\cop.jpg" style="position:absolute;" /><label style="position:absolute;">bla</label> in the IE looks fine, but when I change it to cid:companylogo it doesn't "work"

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `background-image:url("cid:companylogo")`.

Comment: the result is the same. I even tried to use (but I shouldn't) <body background="cid:companylogo"></body> with no result

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what mail client you are viewing this in. Not all mail clients support STYLE or CSS embedded images.

Here is a link regarding CSS support in mail clients:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/